# Using a method for scopes in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am new to Active Record, and, despite reading many docs, I could not find a way to do this. I know it is not the correct way of handling things, ideally the following mapping logic should exist in another table but for now this seems the simplest way to handle it.

I have the following information in a database, and I would like to retrieve it in a special way. I have:

```
|    locations    | value |
|----------------|-------|
|     brazil     |   20  |
|     europe     |   30  |
| restoftheworld |   35  |
```

I want a custom getter method or scope which checks and finds the appropriate entry. Something like this in pseudocode:

```
def findbylocation(location)
  if location exists 
    return row
  elsif location.in_eu?
    return row of 'europe'
  else
    return row of 'restoftheworld'
end
```

What is the best way to write this? Is it a scope or a method?

Note: I am using https://github.com/hexorx/countries for the EU check so there's no problem there.

Comment: Why not use a Hash, instead or Array? Then you will not need a method.

Comment: it is not an Array, they are the database rows. I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: So `europe` and `restoftheworld` are different tables, or all the same table?

Comment: All the same table. It only has 3 rows: 'brazil, 'europe' and 'restoftheworld'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you want to make region validation in memory, as you write in the question's pseudocode, you have to use a `class method` (or `instance method`, depending on how are you going to use it). If you make region validation on a where clause, for instance, you should use a `scope` method.

That is because a `scope` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, and with that you can chain more 'scopes' methods. If you change the returned type object of the scope, you lose the chain ability, and that is pointless.

I am a little confused on how do you want to use `findbylocation` method, and how it behave. Anyway, I strongly recommend you to read [this article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/), that explains very well what is the difference between `scopes` and `methods` in rails.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, for the info. Article was especially good to understand scopes and methods. I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, scopes *are* methods.

They're essentially just shorthand for Rails methods.

---

> I am new to activerecord

Okay so I think you're having a problem because your table structures are incorrect.

ActiveRecord gives us the power of [*associations*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). This is a layer of abstraction you can use to create relationships in your tables, allowing you to perform lookups without having to call 100's of queries.

```
#app/models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :cities #-> you can replace "city" with anything here
   scope :findbylocation, ->(continent) { find_by(name: continent) }
end

#app/models/city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | location_id | name | etc | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :location
end
```

This gives you the ability to call the following:

```
@location = Location.find_by name: "europe"
```

or

```
@location = Location.findbylocation "europe"
```

This will populate the `@location` object, which you'll then be able to call the following:

```
@location.cities.each do |city|
   city.name #-> Bangalore
```

---

You have to understand the power of relational databases, especially when you're building multiple objects:

[image]

I believe the problem you have is you're not modularizing your data properly. IE you're putting it all into a "location" datatable, when really, you should have *locations* as one table, and *cities* (or whatever) in another.

This way, you're not trying to look everything up straight away; you're finding the specific *location* record you need, pulling associated data through it with ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks @rich-peck, I do know the power of relational databases, but I think in my case putting every country in a separate table is not really necessary. I really need three or four different locations but because these locations are tied together with geographical boundaries (e.g. europe) I need a method to define the logic.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I solved it. I am not sure if this is the best way. Feel free to improve or suggest something else if you know a better solution. I created the following method:

```
def self.by_location(location)
  if LocationValue.exists?(:location => location)
    where(location: location)
  elsif location.in_eu?
    where(location: 'europe')
  else
    where(location: 'restoftheworld')
  end
end
```